# How to validate uitextfields when user exits from modal views? (iOS)

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have to validate the text the user enters in some textfields that I have in a modal view. I have the validation on textFieldShouldEndEditing and works fine... unless the user pushes the closing buttons of the view. Then, the view closes regardless the textFieldShouldEndEditing result.

So... how (and where) should I do the validation to be sure the data is always validated?? Or, at least, how could I know if the user is editing some textfield when he/she pushes the cancel or done button of my modal view...

Thanks a lot,

Carlos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` to disable the close button on the modal view until the user ends editing.

Or instead, when the user hits the close button on the modal view, you could check if the modal view should be dismissed using your validation code.

For example, assuming that "self" is the delegate:

```
- (IBAction)closeButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    if ([self textFieldShouldEndEditing:self.textFieldBeingEdited]) {

         // dismiss modal view 

    } 

}
```